# Ionic 2 / Angular 2 - Getting undefined value from global variable

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am facing a weird issue, I am getting undefined in a global variable which I want to use it later. I have put 2 console.log(), the tricky part is Check 2 (as console.log output) fires first instead of Check 1 ). Please have a look at the TS file. In the Check 1, I get the value correctly but it fires after the setRadioButton method, I am little confused as to why it happens like that?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
;import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfilePage {
  userImg : any;
  userName : string;
  profileType :string;
  instr : boolean;
  stud :boolean;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private nativeStorage : NativeStorage) {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem("userLogin").then((data)=>{
       this.userImg = data.picture;
       this.userName = data.name;
    }).catch((c)=>console.log(c));
    this.nativeStorage.getItem("userProfile").then((data)=>{
      this.profileType = data.userProfileType; 
      console.log("Check 1",this.profileType);    
   }).catch((c)=>console.log(c));
   this.setRadioButton()
  }

  setRadioButton()
  {
    console.log("Check 2",this.profileType); 
    if(this.profileType == "Instructor")
    {
      this.instr = true;
      console.log("I")
    }
    if(this.profileType == "Student"){
      this.stud = true;
      console.log("S")
    }
  }
}
```

And the console log output

```
FCMPlugin.js: is created
FCMPlugin.js:41 FCMPlugin Ready OK
bootstrap.js:10 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 1822 ms
index.js:411 DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER 1738 ms
profile.ts:29 Check 2 undefined
profile.ts:22 Check 1 Instructor
```

Comment: Its because this.profileType is defined in an asynchronous context, so in the check 1 you see it printed because the console.log is in the promise where you have acces to it, the check 2, not

Comment: thanks for that explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of timming, you have two async calls and then you have your `this.setRadioButton()`, this function will run before the other two async calls.

If you want to run `this.setRadioButton()` after your *profile.ts:22 Check 1 Instructor*, let's change that code to do what you want.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private nativeStorage : NativeStorage) {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem("userLogin").then((data)=>{
       this.userImg = data.picture;
       this.userName = data.name;
    }).catch((c)=>console.log(c));
    this.nativeStorage.getItem("userProfile").then((data)=>{
      this.profileType = data.userProfileType; 
      console.log("Check 1",this.profileType);    
      this.setRadioButton(); // HERE, this is what you want.
   }).catch((c)=>console.log(c));

  }
```